# Подчеркивание заголовка за контейнером

Tags: css

Подскажите, есть задача сделать подчеркивание заголовка которое должно выходить за выходить за контейнер, и заполнять все пространство слева от контейнера. Прикрепил рисунок с примером. Красной полосой отметил контейнер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможен вот такой вариант с помощью создания дополнительного внешнего блока-обложки. Для него задать нужную вам ширину подчеркивания и сделать это подчеркивание с помощью border-bottom.

```css
  .title_wrap {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 60vw;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-top: 2vh;
   border-bottom: 0.1vh solid #000;
  }
  .title {
   padding-left: 1vh;
   padding-right: 1vh;
   border: 0.1vh solid red;
   border-bottom: none;
   font-size: 3vh;
   color: #000;
   font-family: Arial;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="title_wrap">
  <div class="title">
   Заголовок
  </div>
 </div>
```

Надеюсь это то что Вам нужно!)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, если html менять нельзя, то используем псевдоэлементы:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Работает идеально при условие, если у body нет горизонтального скролла. */
}

.title {
  /* Ниже код не нужен, он для примера */
  display: block;
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  
  /* А вот этот нужен */
  position: relative;
}

.title::before,
.title::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50vw; /* Ну примерно */
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

.title::before {
  right: 100%;
}

.title::after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Заголовок</h1>
```